# Error on load if YAML key has no value (instead of None)?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file with an unknown number of "layers", so when I load it to a Python dictionary it becomes a nested dictionary.

I don't want to allow keys without values in the YAML file. I'd like to either:

- cause errors during `yaml.load()` if there are missing values, or
- identify all `None` values within the resulting nested dictionary.

```
import yaml
with open(input_path, "r") as yaml_file:
    my_dict = yaml.load(yaml_file)
```

Comment: Empty values are perfectly valid YAML, so you're not going to be able to trigger errors during `yaml.load` without writing your own YAML parser.

Comment: Does this mean that you want to convert the dictionary (without empty values) back into a YAML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the `Parser`'s `process_empty_scalar` method to raise an error:

```
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
- 1
- - 2
  -
  - 3
"""

def pes(*args, **kw):
    raise NotImplementedError

yaml.parser.Parser.process_empty_scalar = pes

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)

print(data)
```

The above raises an error, if you comment out the assignment to `.process_empty_scalar` it parses correct.

Please note:

- layers in YAML do not necessarily mean python `dict`s will be formed
- you are using `.load` which is documented to be unsafe and almost guaranteed to be inappropriate.